# Files not fully uploading

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

I've had a few cases (one last night) where I upload a website and a few of the files only partially upload for whatever reason. I have no idea this was the case and ended up with a tonne of emails this morning saying the site isn't working.

In your experience, what would be the best way to ensure files are uploaded in full? I use FileZilla on the Mac and it does not notify me if this has happened.

Any suggestions would be great :)

Comment: Do you have to use ftp? Would rsync be an option?

Comment: Check your queue for errors. In Filezilla you can check on the bottom for "failed transfers"

Comment: @Dr.Tower I've never explored other options. Can you recommend any rsync clients for Mac?

Comment: @Daniel There weren't any failed transfers... That's a bit annoying. Might be time to move on from FileZilla maybe? I do love it for the fact that you can choose to only overwrite files that have been changed...

Comment: @Ben Sinclair I typically use rsync on the command line rather than using a GUI. Also, I don't own a Mac so I can't really offer recommendations for apps on it (other than general command line utilities). Sorry.

Comment: @Ben - just try another client and you will know soon enough if it is the client to blame or something else. personally I love Filezilla for certain features, but I am sure other have theirs. Have a look at fireftp (firefox plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AVG Antivirus? Try disabling surfing/link- and email protection.